# GRE Tunnel Dies in 1 direction

Tags: linux-networking, tunneling, gre

I have built a GRE tunnel over tap0 interface between 2 Centos-7 hosts.  I've done this via the following:

- Host-A: 10.0.10.5
- Host-B: 10.0.20.5

On host A:

```
ip tunnel add tap0 mode gre remote 10.0.20.5 local 10.0.10.5 ttl 255
ip link set tap0 up
ip addr add 10.10.10.1/24 dev tap0
```

on host B:

```
ip tunnel add tap0 mode gre remote 10.0.10.5 local 10.0.20.5 ttl 255
ip link set tap0 up
ip addr add 10.10.10.2/24 dev tap0
```

after doing this, everything is working great.  I can ping on both directions.  The issue is that after a few minutes, the tunnel from Host-A to Host-B dies.  The interface is still up though.

I have run tcpdump on both sides.  tcpdump on Host-A shows packets going out over tap0, but tcpdump on Host-B shows nothing received.

If I log into Host-B and ping Host-A the tunnel is alive again and Host-A can then ping Host-B.  I have done a psuedo-keepalive by creating a cron job on Host-B and ping Host-A once a minute and this keeps the tunnel up, but I don't think this should be necessary.

I haven't found anything in documentation I've read that states GRE tunnels have a timeout.  Has anyone else experienced this ?

Comment: Have you tried to look up your keepalive values in kernel?
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/how-to-turn-on-keepalive-on-linux-interface-4175541981/#post5359804

Comment: Yes, and they are the same on both hosts.  I expect that if that was the issue, the behavior would be the same on both hosts and not unidirectional.

Answer (score 0):

1. You use the stateless GRE tunnel. It's just encapsulation without any establishing and negotiation phases.
2. Run the `tcpdump` and check, what GRE packets go out from one side and arrive to other side.
3. Check the iptables rules with `iptables-save -c` command. You should allow incoming packets of GRE protocol. Check it on both sides.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

4. Also, issue can be caused by statefull firewall between hosts.

Comment: There is no firewall running.  tcpdump shows nothing being received from Host-A -> Host-B until i ping from Host-B to Host-A.

Comment: Seems like between Host-A and Host-B there is stateful firewall.